# Nested JQuery Accordion bugfix isnt working

Tags: jquery, accordion

i want to use this fix for using a nested accordion

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "> h3:not(.item)",
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
   });
});
```

Here you can see my html code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "h3:not(.item)",
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>test1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>testcon1</p>
  <div id="accordion">
      <h3>jojoba</h3>
      <div>jojobacon</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <h3>test2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>testcont2</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Every time when i want to open the jojoba accordion its moving away so im not able to see it anymore.
Im using Google Chrome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is work fine remove header part

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({

    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
    });
    $( "#accordion1" ).accordion({

    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>test1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>testcon1</p>
  <div id="accordion1">
      <h3>jojoba</h3>
      <div>jojobacon</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <h3>test2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>testcont2</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```